# How should I generate Database table on a fresh application install?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, deployment

I've been working on a CMS based in ASP.NET MVC2 using a poco based linq-to-sql repository that is connected to a SQL 2008 database.

I'm nearing completion on the CMS and now I'm thinking about deployment. Ideally, I would like the install process to be something like this:

1. Copy CMS solution to server location
2. Create empty database
3. Change db connection string in web.config to new database
4. Run script to create db tables *(including relationships, constraints, and default data)*.

I'm not sure where to start with this kind of project. I have limited experience working with Stored Procedures. If it's possible to do this progmatically in C# that would be preferable because it would be easier for me to work with.

Any thoughts on where I should start with this?

### Edit - New thoughts

I wonder how difficult it would be to just have a database file (mdf?) that could just be renamed and copied to the sql server. Is that even possible?

Comment: It's probably easier to just run a SQL script that generates the DB

Comment: @bechbd - That's what some of my co-workers are telling me now. To just excecute sql from C# to both create the database and create the tables, relationships, contraints, and default data.

Comment: How many times do you plan on doing this?  Dozens, Hundreds, Thousands?

Comment: @jfar - Ummm... Greater than hundreds ;-) ... by multiple people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest scripting out the creation of your new database and including it as a step in your application install.

You can let SQL Enterprise manager do a lot of the work for you to generate the script too. If you are using enterprise manager just right click your database and select:

**Tasks -> Generate Scripts**

In that wizard select your database and the "Script all objects in selected database". That will end up generating a create script for your entire dB.

You can then take that script file and include it as a resource in your setup program, and run it during setup to create out your full dB.

A good thing to think about if you are going this route is Type data. You may want to include another script step that will populate your type data as the 1st script will only generate your dB, tables, and procs.

Comment: This sounds really cool. What do you mean when you say "Type Data"?

Comment: Typical "Type Data" is a list of status codes or other data used by your application but not created by it, or any data you would want to have in the database at first run.

Answer (score 0):

The two ways I can think of doing this off the top of my head are:

1) Web Setup projects - Similar to this post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx) and add your own custom actions
2) Make it so the first time your application runs it searches for a DB and if one is not found it gives you the option to add the DB/Connection String.

Both of these can be done in C#.  You won't be using Stored Procedures until you have a DB setup because that is where the SPROCS reside.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding the database is probably your best bet.  You can use an .mdb, or SQLite or similiar.  If your using .mdb, just create a template .mdb, then make it a resource of the project.  Then you can copy it to the destination and modify it from there.

I would use SQLite, as its open source, and then you don't have to mess with changing the connection string because you'll just be using the program's install directory to store it.